# expandable listview in android code

Tags: android, fragment, expandablelistview, expandable

** I want to add an expandable list view in the fragment of my android code but I am unable to do it. I have also seen all the posts related to this topic in this website but I can't find a good answer. can anyone help with it?? **

```
HMCfragment.java
public class HMCfragment extends Fragment {

View rootView;
ExpandableListView lv;
 private String[] groups;
private String[][] children;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 groups = new String[] { "Test Header 1", "Test Header 2", "Test Header 3", "Test Header 4" };
 children = new String [][] {{"Debashish Dutta"},{"Deepok Baruah"},{"Rajan Kumar"},{"Aditya         Patel"},{"Piyush dwivedi"}};

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hmc_layout, container, false);  

return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

lv = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
lv.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(groups, children));
lv.setGroupIndicator(null);

}

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater inf;
private String[] groups;
private String[][] children;

public ExpandableListAdapter(String[] groups, String[][] children) {
    this.groups = groups;
    this.children = children;
    inf = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.length;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return children[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

        return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}
```

}
}

Comment: what is the problem? can't you give more detail?

Comment: show us what you've done

Comment: You can find tutorials online to get you started then come ask a more specific question with relevant code and error messages, if any.

Comment: Guys,I have assumed that layout part is easy that's why I have posted only .java file.... I think something is wrong with this code only....kindly help me with it.

Comment: your code just worked for me :/ i just copied and pasted it into a new project..

Comment: @codeMagic I tried the short process but I failed and tutorials are showing very long process for doing such thing...

Comment: @iamkaan really...but I am getting only "Test Header 1" in my output and no expansion also for this group....

Comment: @iamkaan can u send me ur whole code....all xml and java files ???

Answer (score 0):

here is the project i created;

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        View rootView;
        ExpandableListView lv;
        private String[] groups;
        private String[][] children;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            groups = new String[]{"Test Header 1", "Test Header 2", "Test Header 3", "Test Header 4"};
            children = new String[][]{{"Debashish Dutta"}, {"Deepok Baruah"}, {"Rajan Kumar"}, {"Aditya         Patel"}, {"Piyush dwivedi"}};

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            lv = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.exp);
            lv.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(groups, children));
            lv.setGroupIndicator(null);

        }

        public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

            private final LayoutInflater inf;
            private String[] groups;
            private String[][] children;

            public ExpandableListAdapter(String[] groups, String[][] children) {
                this.groups = groups;
                this.children = children;
                inf = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            }

            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                return groups.length;
            }

            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return children[groupPosition].length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return groups[groupPosition];
            }

            @Override
            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
            }

            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
            }

            private class ViewHolder {
                TextView text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_my.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

child_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

parent_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am using fragment in swipe views with tabs so I cannot use "MainActivity extends Activity" as a part of my code..I have to use   expandable list view in one of the tabs but it's not working...can u help me with that??

Comment: there is no difference :/ i used inner fragment class but it will be same if you use separate class for fragment.. it's hard to help remotely without seeing the structure